# Recreating a project's "bin" folder in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, corrupt

My Portable hard drive was damaged recently, on which I had my Eclipse workspace, but during the (expensive) recovery process, it was partially recovered. I have most of my source, but it happens that a project's bin file is empty. It was probably damaged.

Now, I know that the bin file contains only .class files and I can probably regenerate them in a new project and move then to this bin. I may even be able to compile it via console and move it here, but since the project is big, *is there any way to tell eclipse to recompile the classes and put them in the bin?*

I already tried using Project > Clean. It doesn't seem to regenerate them.

Additional info :

- The bin is empty. I cant see even the empty package folders there.
- For one thing, I'm not sure if that is the problem at all. What I really get is an error saying "*Error: Could not find or load main class ut.rm.reader*". But I noticed that other projects having the .class files in the bin work fine. So I'm taking a good guess that this is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your project needs to be a Java project for compiling to work.  As your workspace was damaged, this may be an issue.

Comment: If the bin folder is empty, try deleting it? And then compile and see what happens.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Are you trying to say that Eclipse may think that it is no longer a Java program?

Comment: Go to Project right click>properties>Java build path>Source and check the location of Default Output Folder. Thats the location eclipse places it's class files once you clean the project

Comment: @DirkyJerky Already tried that. Still the same.

Comment: @Hirak I just checked, and it says the bin folder is the output folder.

Comment: Since you don't really know the state of anything in the workspace it would be better to create a new workspace and use 'Import > Existing Project into Workspace' to copy in your project.

Comment: @greg-449 Yeah, just realized that, but it turns out that when the projects are imported, so is the bin folder. So that doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These answers are really good and to the point. If they could not help you it is probably because your .project file is damaged. Try this:

Close your project and remove from the workspace (delete the project but not the physical files).

Delete the .project file, which is in the root of the project you just closed.

Make a backup of your project (always a good idea)

In Eclipse, create a new project and copy the files into the new project. Make sure it is a Java project.

As soon as you rebuild the project you should see the bin folder.

Comment: That worked pretty much fine, except for a few hitches, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a kludge, but go to the compiler settings for the project (configure build path) and make a change (e.g. change one of the Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings from warning to error).  When you click apply you'll be told you need to recompile the entire project.  Once the project is recompiled (and your classes recreated), go back and undo the compiler setting you changed.

Comment: Tried it. My bin is still empty. Maybe the project meta is damaged? Meybe I should delete it and make Eclipse rebuild it?

Comment: If it's just a basic java project then try creating a new java project and copying the contents of the srcs folder from the old damaged project to the new project.

Answer (score 0):

Delete bin folder.

Right Click on Project's Name and choose "Refresh" which will generate (empty)directory structure.

Run the project(Click on Play symbol).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an issue with the current project but a project you are dependent on.
Right click on your project and Select: **Build Path > Configure Build Path**

Under the projects tab, check to see if any other projects are listed.  You may need to resolve the Java Compiler settings or libraries in that project.  If there is an issue with that project, there should be a "red exclamation" mark on that project.

Make sure that your JRE environment is compatible with the external JAR files and dependent projects.